# How to handle memory errors with Itertool even though I am iterating directly

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem I am facing is that when I am running the below code for the  list A and B, I am getting Memory error. Is there any other way to handle the Memory error for this problem.
When the number of elements in the list A and B is less than 15, then it is running fine.

```
import numpy as np
import string
from itertools import permutations
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd
import random

A = []
B = []

for i in range(0,25):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    A.append(x)

for i in range(0,25):
    x = random.randint(10,20)
    B.append(x)


def function1(t):
    f=sum(t)
    g = np.prod(t)
    return f,g

def vec(I,  J):
    return list(it.product(I, J))

def add(A):
    return A[0] + A[1]

def product(A):
    return A[0]*A[1]

array1 = []
array1_u = []
for L in range(0, len(A)+1):
    for subset in it.combinations(A, L):
        combinations=list(subset)
        c1, c2 = function1(combinations)
        array1.append(c1)
        array1_u.append(c2)
    
    
array2 = []
array2_u = []
for L1 in range(0, len(B)+1):
    for subset1 in it.combinations(B, L1):
        element_combo=list(subset1)
        d1, d2 = function1(element_combo)
        array2.append(d1)
        array2_u.append(d2)


e1=vec(array1,array2)
list1 = map(add, e1)
        
f1=vec(array1_u, array2_u)
list2 = map(product, f1)
       
cost = np.dot(list(list1), np.transpose(list(list2)))
print(cost)
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: When I am running this code for more than 20 elements in A and B, it is showing Memory Error after sometime.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have provided all the specific details. I have a Memory error when I am running this code for  more than 20 elements in A and B?

Comment: 20 elements in A and B each? So your lists grow to a trillion elements?

Comment: Yes, it grows exponentially...